# WatchKit Catalog sample code bug

Tags: ios, watchkit

I can build and run this app with Xcode Version 6.3 (6D520o). But in the main interface, the app responds to taps in table rows by triggering the wrong row.

The top row (Label) works fine, but tapping the next row (Button) makes the Label row highlight and transition. The next row (Switch) also triggers the top row's action.

Similar problems appear in the sub-views.

Comment: So raise a radar. There is no question here.

Comment: I'll spell it out: is this a fixable bug in the code? If so, how? If not, is there a workaround? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You will have same problem in the Xcode 6.3 beta too when you try to press the button. I though that It was a bug in that Xcode, you should try the Xcode 6.2 beta now.

Answer (score 2):

The 6.3 beta is riddled with bugs at the moment. If you're aiming to have your app ready for the launch of Apple Watch, you should be working with the 6.2 beta.

It's been mentioned a few times, but here's Jake Behrens (Dev Evangelist at Apple) mentioning it on Twitter: https://twitter.com/behrens/status/565546489041412098